# Pytorch/torchvision - How to increase limit of detectable objects

Tags: python, pytorch, object-detection, torchvision

I am new to Pytorch and so far it has been incredible. I am using it to count the number of pills in an image. I have found that in the majority of my images the max number of objects that it detects is 100. For the picture below it reaches a max count of 100 with the confidence around .6. After that it doesn't increase anymore even down to .1 confidence. I haven't been able to find anything in the docs or any other places online. I am using the fasterrcnn_resnet50_fpn model. Below is the code that load the trained model and evaluate the image. Any tips or even different packages that would be able to count all objects would be super helpful.

```
## Loading the trained module
loaded_model = get_model(num_classes = 2)
loaded_model.load_state_dict(torch.load('Pillcount/model'))

os.chdir('../pytorchobjdet/vision')

class CountDataset(torch.utils.data.Dataset):
    def __init__(self, root, data_file, transforms=None):
        self.root = root
        self.transforms = transforms
        self.imgs = sorted(os.listdir(os.path.join(root, "count")))
        self.path_to_data_file = data_file
    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        # load images and bounding boxes
        img_path = os.path.join(self.root, "count", self.imgs[idx])
        img = Image.open(img_path).convert("RGB")
        box_list = parse_one_annot(self.path_to_data_file, 
        self.imgs[idx])
        boxes = torch.as_tensor(box_list, dtype=torch.float32)
        num_objs = len(box_list)
        # there is only one class
        labels = torch.ones((num_objs,), dtype=torch.int64)
        image_id = torch.tensor([idx])
        area = (boxes[:, 3] - boxes[:, 1]) * (boxes[:, 2] - boxes[:,
        0])
        # suppose all instances are not crowd
        iscrowd = torch.zeros((num_objs,), dtype=torch.int64)
        target = {}
        target["boxes"] = boxes
        target["labels"] = labels
        target["image_id"] = image_id
        target["area"] = area
        target["iscrowd"] = iscrowd
        if self.transforms is not None:
                img, target = self.transforms(img, target)
        return img, target
    def __len__(self):
            return len(self.imgs)


dataset_count = CountDataset(root='../../Pill_Object_Detection', 
                        data_file = "../../Pill_Object_Detection/count_labels.csv",
                        transforms = get_transform(train=False))

idx = 1
img, _ = dataset_count[idx]
#put the model in evaluation mode
loaded_model.eval()
with torch.no_grad():
   prediction = loaded_model([img])
image = Image.fromarray(img.mul(255).permute(1, 2,0).byte().numpy())
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
# draw groundtruth
count = 0
for element in range(len(prediction[0]["boxes"])):
   boxes = prediction[0]["boxes"][element].cpu().numpy()
   score = np.round(prediction[0]["scores"][element].cpu().numpy(),
                    decimals= 4)
   if score > 0.6:
      draw.rectangle([(boxes[0], boxes[1]), (boxes[2], boxes[3])], 
      outline ="red", width =3)
      draw.text((boxes[0], boxes[1]), text = str(score))
      count +=1
print(f'count = {count}')
image
```

[image]

Comment: Usually we deal with this situation by split the image to many evened size images, and sum the count, or using [YOLO-like](https://pjreddie.com/darknet/yolo/) detector

Answer (score 1):

The advice from the comment above was very helpful. I used the YOLO5vs model and it did an incredible job. This [tutorial](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-train-a-custom-object-detection-model-with-yolo-v5-917e9ce13208) had a super easy set up that had you upload the annotated images into roboflow, and then it had some google colab tutorials set up for almost all of the current object detectors out there. Here is the result. I just need to give better quality training data but it did extremely well for the few pictures that I gave it. It can count well over 150 objects in the same image no problem.
[image]